# How to restore mongoDb collection BSON backup files to docker abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-base?

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu

I have made a backup from a mongoDb collection with the following command

```
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 9001 -d meteor -c products
```

I have copied the dump folder recursively to my server with the following command

```
scp -r dump root@66.204.148.25:/root
```

I can not restore with the following command

```
docker exec -i mongodb mongorestore -d mew -c audioQuestions_Joker dump/meteor
```

the files are there but I get the following message
2020-01-12T11:38:10.863+0000    Failed: mongorestore target 'dump/meteor' invalid: stat dump/meteor: no such file or directory

What would be the correct command to restore the collection backup from the BSON files?

FYI docker abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-base

Thanks

Comment: It's because docker searches `dump/meteor` inside mongodb container

Comment: yes, but how can I restore the files that are on the host and not on the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `sudo` privileges.

1 Modify `docker-compose.*` file for MongoDB container and add new volume

Suppose you have something like this:

```
 mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - "./local/path:/data/db"
      - "./local/tmp/path:/home"
    restart: always
    command: --auth
```

2 You need to `build`

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

3 Copy inside `./local/tmp/path` you `dump` folder and check if MongoDB container has access to it.

```
sudo docker ps
sudo docker exec -it mongodb_CONTAINER ID /bin/bash
# ls /home - If you see there dump folder, continue step 4
```

4 Now, execute MongoDB restore (you may do it inside MongoDB container)

```
mongorestore -d mew -c audioQuestions_Joker /home/dump/meteor
```

5 If you have restored successfully, update again docker-compose and remove `- "./local/tmp/path:/home"` and build.